# Webscraping with Selenium, load more button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from a website that after making the query presents a 25 results page with a load more button that load additionally 25 results.

I would like to extract the data and at the end of the first 25 results selenium will click on the load more button and then continue to scrape the information until the load more button exists.

I've this code but I don't know how to continue.

```
# Import necessary libraries

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

# Define the keywords to search for

what = 'architeto'
where = 'Torino'

# Initialize the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the website
driver.get("https://www.paginegialle.it/")
driver.maximize_window()

# Find the search input fields and enter the keywords
# what is called 'cosa' and where is called 'dove'

search_what = driver.find_element(By.ID, "cosa")
search_what.send_keys(f'{what}')

# Clear the location field and enter the location
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'dove').clear()

# Enter the location
search_where = driver.find_element(By.ID, "dove")
search_where.send_keys(f'{where}')

# Click the search button
search_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@type='submit']")
search_button.click()

# Wait for the search results to load
driver.implicitly_wait(2)

# Find all the search results and save them
search_results = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "search-itm")

# Wait for 5 seconds for the page to fully load

time.sleep(5)

# Loop through each search result and get the data
for result in search_results:

    # Get the link to each search result and open it in a new tab
    link = result.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a").get_attribute("href")

    # Open a new window
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")

    # Switch to the new window and open new URL
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    driver.get(link)

    # Wait for 5 seconds for the page to fully load


    # Get the data

    #Company name
    try:
        nome_azienda = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"scheda-azienda__companyTitle").text
        print(nome_azienda)
    except:
        nome_azienda = None


    # Company category
    try:
        categoria = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"scheda-azienda__companyCategory").text
        print(categoria)
    except:
        categoria = None
    time.sleep(2)

    # Company address
    try:
        indirizzo = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"scheda-azienda__companyAddress").text
        print(indirizzo)
    except:
        indirizzo = None


    # Company phone number
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"bttn--yellow").click()
        telefono = driver.find_element(By.ID,"mainPhoneNumber_desk").text
        print(telefono)
    except:
        telefono = None


    # Company website
    try:
        sito_web = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a").get_attribute("href")
        print(sito_web)
    except:
        sito_web = None


    # Company description
    try:
        descrizione = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"scheda-azienda__description").text
        print(descrizione)
    except:
        descrizione = None


    # Company characteristics
    try:
        caratteristiche = driver.find_element(By.ID,"infoComp").text
        print(caratteristiche)
    except:
        caratteristiche = None


    # Save the data in a dictionary
    data = {"nome_azienda": nome_azienda, "categoria": categoria, "indirizzo": indirizzo, "telefono": telefono, "sito_web": sito_web, "descrizione": descrizione, "caratteristiche": caratteristiche}

    # Write the data to an excel file
    reader = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists="overlay")

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Nome Azienda': [nome_azienda], 'Categoria': [categoria], 'Indirizzo': [indirizzo], 'Telefono': [telefono], 'Sito Web': [sito_web], 'Descrizione': [descrizione], 'Caratteristiche': [caratteristiche]})
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, startrow=len(reader) + 1)
    writer.close()



    # Close the active tab
    driver.close()

    # Switch back to the first tab and continue with the next iteration of the loop
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

# Close the webdriver
driver.quit()
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Thank you enormously

Comment: Upon clicking the *Load More* button, the URL changes, you can use that to scrape the next set.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Open the URL --> Search for the results --> Keep clicking on <kbd>Load more</kbd> button until all the results are displayed and no more <kbd>Load more</kbd> button is displayed. Once this is done, do your scraping as all the required elements will be visible now.

**Working code:**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.paginegialle.it/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

# accept cookies
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accetta e Chiudi']"))).click()

# Enter values in text box and click on Search button
driver.find_element(By.ID, "cosa").send_keys("architeto")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "dove").clear()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "dove").send_keys("Torino")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@type='submit']").click()

# Below while loop will keep clicking Load more button until all results are loaded
while True:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='MOSTRA ALTRI RISULTATI']"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    if(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='MOSTRA ALTRI RISULTATI']//parent::a[@style='display: none;']")) >=1):
        break

# Now that the page has completed loaded all the results, do the scraping now
# Write your scraping code here
```

Comment: @ManekyNeko - If this has resolved your issue, accept the answer so that its not left un-answered.